# Is there a hook to monitor activity on a bluetooth serial port

Tags: bluetooth, windows-ce, serial-port

Is there any way of monitoring activity over a bluetooth connection either using a software hook or an external bluetooth monitor, where the bluetooth is emulating a RS232 serial port.

When I'm using a cabled connection, I could use an in-line datascope for this activity, which was basically checking whether comms between a PC and external device were taking place.  The connection features a PC at one end talking to a Windows CE device at the other end.

Answer (score 2):

Sysinternals's Portmon can monitor serial ports, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx  Presumably it can monitor Bluetooth virtual serial ports...

Answer (score 1):

You can get over the air tracing of a Bluetooth connection using [Frontline](http://www.fte.com/products/FTS4BT-01.asp). I think you need to be able to set default security and encryption for this to work though.

If your problem is in the air interface, this is a pretty good tool.